# Why do I get uninitialized constant Exchange::Logger (NameError)?

Tags: ruby

My application is giving me this error:

```
/usr/local/www/sl-exchange/lib/exchange.rb:25:in 'initialize': uninitialized constant Exchange::Logger (NameError).
```

What gem or file does `Logger` come from?

```
class Exchange

  attr_accessor :logger, :options 

  QUEUE_INTERVAL = 15
  MONTHLY_PROCESS_DAY = 1 
  MINUTE = 60 
  HOUR_IN_SECONDS = 60 * 60 

  def initialize()

    # Setup Logging
    self.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) #<-- this line is giving me issues
            ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I got what you mean, but if you're just asking about what to require, there at [Ruby Doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) you can see the Logger class is defined at logger.rb, so `require 'logger'` should do the trick.

Also, there's no need to use the self.logger method, you can just access the variable using `@logger`

```
@logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```